# Non Blocking IO with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, nonblocking

I am trying to wrap my head around non-blocking io for making http requests from a `Spring Boot 2` application. My use case is such that I need to make a service-to-service `HTTP` calls without dedicating a thread to every single outgoing `HTTP` call.

Would appreciate if someone could point me to the right library and/or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article that mentions a whole bunch of option:

https://dzone.com/articles/high-concurrency-http-clients-on-the-jvm

If your answer isn't in there, Google "non blocking http request java". There are lots of options out there. The right option for you depends on your use case and need not have anything to do with Spring Boot.